# Windows 8 -> 8.1 upgrade, how to get my old account settings back?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and it forcibly asked me to create a new Microsoft account. I was using a local account before.

Now all my settings are gone due to using a new Microsoft account, but the old, local user folder is still there with all the installed programs (C:\Users\J). Is it possible to log back in with my old local account so i don't have to reconfigure everything from start?

I checked under User management and it didn't display my old account, even tough the folder still exists (thank god for that, i guess).

Comment: If your username is not listed in User Mangement then there is nothing you can do.  Are you sure its not listed provide a screenshot of the listed accounts blocking out the Microsoft Account information.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. It appears that the local user account has been renamed and the shortcuts to the old folders have been replaced with shortcuts to new locations. There may be other changes too but I haven't spotted them as I've only just upgraded.

1. You can confirm that your account is a local account by

   - Opening Windows Explorer (press the <kbd>windows</kbd> key and the <kbd>E</kbd> key at the same time)
   - Right-click on your computer and select [Manage]
   - Click on Local Users and Computers
   - Click on the Users folder
   - If your new account name appears in here then it is a local account. I am unsure if this is true as my old local user account name is identical in some ways to the new username.
   - If your old account name doesn't appear but Outlook still has all your data then it would appear that your old account has been renamed to the new account
2. You can change the shortcuts back to the old folder locations:

   - Open Windows Explorer (press the <kbd>windows</kbd> and the <kbd>E</kbd> key at the same time)
   - Right click on Documents and select Properties
   - Click on the Location tab
   - Click on the [Move] button
   - Select the old location and then click on the [Select Folder] button
   - Verify the path is now correct and then click on the [OK] button
   - At the warning popup select the [No] button to prevent these new files being added to your pre-existing files
   - All your old files in that old folder should now be visible
   - Repeat the above steps for Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos